# TLS/SSL behind company firewall

Tags: networking, ssl, firewall, https

i have some `https` websites than behind the company firewall require over 15 seconds for display the page. But:

- using internet (out of the firewall), these are pretty fast
- over `http` are pretty fast

It seem a client/browser timeout for validate the certificate (or the certificate authority).

There is an address that can i open into the firewall for validate those certificate?

My certificate authority are Comodo and Symantec.

For Comodo i found:

- http://crl.usertrust.com
- http://ocsp.usertrust.com
- http://crl.comodoca.com
- http://crt.comodoca.com
- http://ocsp.comodoca.com
- https://secure.comodo.com
- http://crl.comodoca.com.cdn.cloudflare.net

for Symantec:

- http://sr.symcb.com
- https://d.symcb.com
- http://s2.symcb.com
- http://www.symauth.com
- http://s1.symcb.com
- http://sv.symcb.com

Comment: You will first need to identify what stage is the main reason of the 15 seconds delay, by using for example developer tools in your browser and/or capturing packets on the network. Often the main reason of initial delay is DNS resolution, so start by checking that.